# React routing with flask and jinja

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, get, url-routing

I have an app with flask as the backend and react in the frontend.

In the main page there is a link to "`/users/<user_id>`" which leads to a user details page. The page should show the basic details of the users, which should be queried from a db.

I can't understand what is the best way to do this.
I looked at react-router, but it seems like I would not be able to trigger that GET request to the server and back to the client, because it would only load the appropriate react element.

The other option is to do a regular flask route with `@app.route`, but then how can I load a template which will pass the user details to the react components that will be rendered in this template? The jinja parameters are only available in html and I need them in my users_page.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include jinja parameters in your javascript file unless you're willing to render it with jinja for each request.

Another way would be to have your react component make an ajax request for the details it needs. To support this you can set up a regular flask route to return them as a JSON response - [see the docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify).

You can see an example of this in the [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state).